# Extraer dos palabras específicas

Tags: r, regex

Tengo el siguiente df:

```
datos<-data.frame(
  col1=c("rojo","rojo","verde","rojo","verde","rojo"),
  col2=c("WS2 Fr Tomate ","WS2 Fr Plus stiv","E1 pata1ta","E2 Fr Plus limon2","E1 tom2ate","G1 Fr manza1na"), col3=c(NA,NA,"Patatas",NA,"Tomates",NA),stringsAsFactors=F
)
```

```
   col1              col2    col3
1  rojo    WS2 Fr Tomate     <NA>
2  rojo  WS2 Fr Plus stiv    <NA>
3 verde        E1 pata1ta Patatas
4  rojo E2 Fr Plus limon2    <NA>
5 verde        E1 tom2ate Tomates
6  rojo    G1 Fr manza1na    <NA>
```

Quiero capturar `Fr` y `Fr Plus` solo si la `col1 = rojo` y añadirlo
a la col3

Busco el patrón (mal):

```
patron <- ".*(Fr)|.*(Fr Plus).*"


datos$col3 <- ifelse(datos$col1=="rojo" & grepl(patron, datos$col2), 
                     gsub(patron, "\\1\\2", datos$col2),datos$col3)
```

```
   col1              col2        col3
1  rojo    WS2 Fr Tomate   Fr Tomate 
2  rojo  WS2 Fr Plus stiv     Fr Plus
3 verde        E1 pata1ta     Patatas
4  rojo E2 Fr Plus limon2     Fr Plus
5 verde        E1 tom2ate     Tomates
6  rojo    G1 Fr manza1na Fr manza1na
```

Se me cuela el Tomate (`Fr Tomate`) y el manza1na (`Fr manza1na`) y no consigo quitarlo. En esos casos debería mostrar solamente `Fr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si solamente te interesa extraer el valor, se puede hacer con [`stringr::str_extract()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_extract).

En cuanto al patrón, creo que es más sencillo de lo que estás pensando. Simplemente te interesa `"Fr"`, opcionalmente seguido por `" Plus"`.

```
Fr(?: Plus)?
```

Código:

```
library(stringr)

datos<-data.frame(
  col1=c("rojo","rojo","verde","rojo","verde","rojo"),
  col2=c("WS2 Fr Tomate ","WS2 Fr Plus stiv","E1 pata1ta","E2 Fr Plus limon2","E1 tom2ate","G1 Fr manza1na"),
  col3=c(NA,NA,"Patatas",NA,"Tomates",NA),stringsAsFactors=F
)


datos$col3 <- ifelse(datos$col1=="rojo", str_extract(datos$col2, "Fr(?: Plus)?"), datos$col3)
```

```
   col1              col2    col3
1  rojo    WS2 Fr Tomate       Fr
2  rojo  WS2 Fr Plus stiv Fr Plus
3 verde        E1 pata1ta Patatas
4  rojo E2 Fr Plus limon2 Fr Plus
5 verde        E1 tom2ate Tomates
6  rojo    G1 Fr manza1na      Fr
```

Comment: Gracias, pero tiene el problema que sobreescribe la col3, cuando más bien buscaba que añadiera el dato. Si quiero hacer lo mismos con "extra" y "extra plus" "Fr y Fr Plus" desaparece de col3. Buscaba que se añadiese el patrón a lo que ya habia en la columna

Comment: Edito la pregunta original para que se entienda mejor

Comment: Bueno, ahí es donde tenés que tomar la respuesta y adaptarla a tu caso... Edité la respuesta para que sobreescriba sólo cuando es `rojo`, pero realmente la pregunta tuya tiene que ver con el regex, no con el resto del código.. Si la condición no es que sobreescriba todos los rojos, cambiá la condición del `ifelse()`